# WPF Expander Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

Does anyone know of a way to change the style of an expander if a IDataError validation occurs in a control held within the expander. E.g.

```
<Expander Header="Details">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Brand.DESCRIPTION,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
</Expander>
```

So if the textbox has an error the style of my expander will change (go red maybe).
I'm looking to make this as generic as possible so without binding to each control within the expander manually if possible.

Comment: Sounds like custom classes! Custom expander, custom inner controls, inner controls fire IDataError events, expander subscribes to those events, handles accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the Attached Event `Validation.Error` (which is raised everytime a validation error is added or removed) through an Attached Behavior. To make this work you need to add `NotifyOnValidationError=True` to the bindings.

This Attached Behavior, `ChildValidation`, subscribes to the `Validation.Error` event for the `Expander` which is bubbled up if `NotifyOnValidationError` is set to True on the bindings. Since several `Control`s may be located within the `Expander` it also need to keep track of the count of Validation Errors that's currently active to determine if a Red Border should be displayed or not. It could look like this

**Xaml**

```
<Expander Header="Details"
            behaviors:ChildValidationBehavior.ChildValidation="True">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Brand.DESCRIPTION,
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                            ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                            NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
</Expander>
```

**ChildValidationBehavior**

```
public static class ChildValidationBehavior 
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ErrorCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ErrorCount",
                                            typeof(int),
                                            typeof(ChildValidationBehavior));
    private static void SetErrorCount(DependencyObject element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ErrorCountProperty, value);
    }
    private static int GetErrorCount(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(ErrorCountProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildValidationProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ChildValidation", 
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(ChildValidationBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnChildValidationPropertyChanged));
    public static bool GetChildValidation(DependencyObject obj) 
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(ChildValidationProperty); 
    }
    public static void SetChildValidation(DependencyObject obj, bool value) 
    {
        obj.SetValue(ChildValidationProperty, value); 
    }
    private static void OnChildValidationPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dpo, 
                                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = dpo as Control;
        if (control != null)
        { 
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true) 
            {
                SetErrorCount(control, 0);
                Validation.AddErrorHandler(control, Validation_Error);
            } 
            else 
            {
                Validation.RemoveErrorHandler(control, Validation_Error);
            } 
        } 
    }
    private static void Validation_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
        {
            SetErrorCount(control, GetErrorCount(control)+1);
        }
        else
        {
            SetErrorCount(control, GetErrorCount(control)-1);
        }
        int errorCount = GetErrorCount(control);
        if (errorCount > 0)
        {
            control.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            control.ClearValue(Control.BorderBrushProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. I can see the Validation_Error is getting called however the expander does not update. I have a style applied to all expanders, could this be to blame?

Comment: Found an alternative anyway. Modified the Validation_Error to cast control to an expander and update the foreground (text colour) and open the expander. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I attempted to use this to change the header color to red.  When I do this (control.foreground = brushes.Red) it turns all the headers of the children under the expander to red also, which in my case are groupboxes.  Any way to just change the foreground of the expander and not its content?